# if a function is linear, then it is its own derivative

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

LEt $f: U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^m$, $U$ open. Suppose $f$ is a linear transformation, and differentiable at $x_0 $. Then, my question is, do we have have that $Df(x_0) = f $ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; by definition/construction, the derivative is the best local linear approximation of the (local) change of a differentiable function. The best local linear approximation to a linear function $L$ is then $L$ itself. Strictly speaking the differential is the linear function that locally approximates the change of the function, and the derivative (or its higher-dimensional versions) is the numerical value of the differential at a point. The differential of a  differentiable function from $\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ is then the tangent line at a point, for maps $ f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R ; z=f(x,y) $ is a tangent plane, etc.